# Tooltip box looks weird When input text is too long

Tags: html, css

We have a tooltip box whose css are below:

```
.radioButton-tooltip
 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 205px;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 35px;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -17px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: url(images/tooltip.png) 0 center no-repeat;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: none;
    text-align:left;
    z-index:100;

}
 .radioButton-tooltip:before, .radioButton-tooltip:after, .radioButton-tooltip .before, .radioButton-tooltip .after 
 {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(images/tooltip.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index:100;
}

.radioButton-tooltip:before,  .radioButton-tooltip .before
{
    background-position: 0 top;
    top: -10px;
    z-index:100;
}

.radioButton-tooltip:after, .radioButton-tooltip .after
{
    background-position: 0 bottom;
    bottom: -10px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Normally, it works fine. As shown:

[image]

However, when the text becomes very long, it looks as below:

[image]

I am not quite sure how this is caused but I am assuming it is because the text is too long which exceeds the original tooltip.png's maximum length. But the question is how should I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Add a working demo to understand the HTML structure

Comment: Can you include your HTML as well

Comment: Add ` overflow-y: scroll;` if you don't want the layout to be broken. It might be the absolute position you're using and it is in `px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using pure CSS with this and don't mess with using image splicing/sprites. That's quite an old technique.

```css
.tool-tip {
  left: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  padding: 15px;
  max-width: 250px;
  color: #fff;
  font: normal 100% Arial, sans-serif;
}
.tool-tip:after, .tool-tip:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: calc(50% - 15px);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
}
.tool-tip:after {
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #444;
}
/*.tool-tip:before {
  top: calc(50% - 18px);
  left: -21px;
  border-top: 18px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
  border-right: 18px solid #fff;
}*/

.tool-tip:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tool-tip">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu lorem sit amet erat pellentesque gravida. Cras scelerisque, lorem a feugiat blandit, risus eros interdum orci, non aliquet dui ex a ipsum. 
</div>

<div class="tool-tip">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have adjusted that and it is pretty much working. Is there any chance we can make the small triangle black instead of white? I have tried several things but no luck yet.

Comment: No need to worry about that. I guess it will require a little bit more complex html structure and then it can be achieved. Thank you for that.

Comment: I've edited my post to change the arrow to black but you're correct in thinking there will be more HTML elements needing to be added to make it exactly like your example. The one I provided is the closest you can get due to CSS limits, you can't add a shadow to border triangles.